# Docker Mysql link to another container

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I created a Docker container with Apache on it. Everything works, except that I can't link MySQL (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) to my container, and I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Here are the steps I did:

1. I run mysql server container

`docker run --name mysqlserver -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass123 -d mysql/mysql-server:latest`

2. Then, I run and link my Apache Docker:

`docker run -it --link mysqlserver:mysql -v "$(pwd)":/var/www/html -p 80:80 -p 3306:3306 apachebash`

But I cant access MySQL.

Comment: `But I cant access MySQL` - What command did you type, and what was the error message?

Comment: i tried running drupal inside apache i expect that i can connect to mysql since i have link it to the container but to no avail

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

Comment: @adamMatan i figured it out i need check /etc/hosts inside my apache docker container and i saw that the ip is 
`172.17.0.139    mysql df67d7b52743 drupaldb`
i used that and i am able to run mysql now thanks for your help

Comment: Great, @jry, and welcome to Stackoverflow.com.
It is encouraged to post your solution as an answer, so that others will be able to benefit from your research.

Comment: i see ill do that . thanks @AdamMatan